# Function runs when any text input is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calc

I have made a calculator tool that has about 10 different text inputs for the user to complete before clicking the "calculate" button to run a function and return the calculated values. I want the function to run every time a text input is changed, rather than using a button. Here is a simple example to work with:

```js
function calculate() {
 //Inputs ("parseInt" converts string to Int)
 var A = parseInt(document.getElementById("A").value);
 var B = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").value);  
 var total = A*B;

 //Output
 document.getElementById("total").value = total;
};
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="A"> x
<input type="text" id="B">
<input type="button" onClick="calculate()" value="Calculate"> = 
<output id="total"></output>
```

The above example has two text inputs that are multiplied when the button is clicked. What would be the best way to do this, so that the output is calculated every time a text input is changed? Keep in mind that the actual project has multiple text inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the elements `change`, `keyup` and `mouseup` events to trigger your `calculate` function.

I'd recommend a couple of loops and `addEventListener`:

```js
function calculate() {
  //Inputs ("parseInt" converts string to Int)
  var A = parseInt(document.getElementById("A").value);
  var B = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").value);
  var total = A * B;

  //Output
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
};

for (var elm of [document.getElementById("A"), document.getElementById("B"), document.getElementById("Calculate")]) {
  for (var st of ['change', 'keyup', 'mouseup', 'click']) {
    elm.addEventListener(st, calculate)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="A"> x
<input type="number" id="B">
<input type="button" id="Calculate" value="Calculate"> =
<output id="total"></output>
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked the best for my situation. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Execute the function on `oninput` in both the text input as well:

```js
function calculate() {
  //Inputs ("parseInt" converts string to Int)
  var A = parseInt(document.getElementById("A").value);
  var B = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").value);  
  var total = A*B;

  //Output
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="A" oninput="calculate()"> x
<input type="text" id="B" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="button" onClick="calculate()" value="Calculate"> = 
<output id="total"></output>
```

**OR:** You might want to attach the event with `forEach()`:

```js
function calculate() {
  //Inputs ("parseInt" converts string to Int)
  var A = parseInt(document.getElementById("A").value);
  var B = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").value);  
  var total = A*B;

  //Output
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
};

var allTextInput = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
[...allTextInput].forEach(el => el.addEventListener('input', calculate));
```

```html
<input type="text" id="A" oninput="calculate()"> x
<input type="text" id="B" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="button" onClick="calculate()" value="Calculate"> = 
<output id="total"></output>
```

Comment: This is rather not optimal as OP has mentioned he has many such input controls and you are suggesting to add `oninput="calculate()"` to all of those which is surely not flexible

Comment: Also note that calling `forEach()` on `querySelectorAll()` will not work in IE

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" onInput="calculate()" id="A"> x
<input type="text" onInput="calculate()" id="B"> x
<input type="text" onInput="calculate()" id="C"> =
<output id="total"></output>



<script>
function calculate() {
//Inputs ("parseInt" converts string to Int)
var A = parseInt(document.getElementById("A").value);
var B = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").value);
var C = parseInt(document.getElementById("C").value);

var total;
if(isNaN(A)){
  A=1;
}
if(isNaN(B)){
  B=1;
}
if(isNaN(C)){
  C=1;
}
total = A*B*C;  
//Output
document.getElementById("total").value = total;
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can associate a class name to all those input fields and add a `keyup` event to it. Very suitable for multiple elements as you are managing everything by a class name which has less chances of error or bug

**USING JQUERY**

```js
$('.calculateText').keyup(function(){
  var A = parseInt(document.getElementById("A").value);
  var B = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").value);
  var total = A * B;

  //Output
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='calculateText' type="text" id="A"> x
<input class='calculateText' type="text" id="B">
<input type="button" value="Calculate"> =
<output id="total"></output>
```

**USING JAVASCRIPT**

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.calculateText');
elems.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    var A = parseInt(document.getElementById("A").value);
    var B = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").value);
    var total = A * B;

    //Output
    document.getElementById("total").value = total;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='calculateText' type="text" id="A"> x
<input class='calculateText' type="text" id="B">
<input type="button" value="Calculate"> =
<output id="total"></output>
```

Comment: Note that calling `forEach()` on `querySelectorAll()` will not work in IE

Answer (score 1):

You can execute `calculate` on `onInput` of the inputs. One check you might need to have in place is of **blank inputs or of non-numerical input value** or else it will show `NaN` in result.

```js
function calculate() {
 //Inputs ("parseInt" converts string to Int)
 var A = parseInt(document.getElementById("A").value);
 var B = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").value);
  var total;
  if(isNaN(A) || isNaN(B)){
    total = "Invalid Operation";
  }
  else{
   total = A*B;  
  }

 //Output
 document.getElementById("total").value = total;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" onInput="calculate()" id="A"> x
<input type="text" onInput="calculate()" id="B">
<output id="total"></output>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can also call the `calculate()` function from the `input` event of your text fields:

```js
document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', calculate);

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input')).forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('input', calculate);
});

function calculate() {
  var A = parseInt(document.getElementById("A").value) || 0;
  var B = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").value) || 0;
  var total = A * B;

  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="A" class="input"> x
<input type="text" id="B" class="input">
<input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calculate"> =
<output id="total"></output>
```

Note the coercing of `NaN` to `0` in the calculation, and also the removal of the outdated `onclick` attribute; always use unobtrusive event handlers where possible.

Comment: A bit off topic, but showing how you changed NaN to 0 actually really helped me out as well. So thanks :)

Comment: Feel free to change the accepted answer, then :) I'd suggest using a single `input` handler over attaching the multiple unnecessary event handlers as the answer you chose does.

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation instead, and listen for `input` events on the entire container that contains all input fields - that way, you only ever add one listener, rather than manually adding a listener for every single element:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('input', ({ target }) => {
  console.log('Saw a change on element ' + target.id);
  if (target.id === 'A' || target.id === 'B') {
    var A = parseInt(document.getElementById("A").value);
    var B = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").value);  
    var total = A*B;

    //Output
    document.getElementById("total").value = total;
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
<input type="text" id="A"> x
<input type="text" id="B">
</div>
<output id="total"></output>
<div>
<input type="text" id="C"> +
<input type="text" id="D">
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" id="E"> /
<input type="text" id="F">
</div>
```